# Rewrite a query with GROUP BY ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2014

Microsoft has deprecated [GROUP BY ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms175028(v=sql.90)) and while the query might work now, I'd like to future-proof this query for future SQL upgrades.

Currently, my query is:

```
SELECT       qt.QueueName AS [Queue] ,
             COUNT ( qt.QueueName ) AS [#ofUnprocessedEnvelopes] ,
             COUNT (   CASE WHEN dq.AssignedToUserID = 0 THEN 1
                            ELSE NULL
                       END
                   ) AS [#ofUnassignedEnvelopes] ,
             MIN ( dq.DocumentDate ) AS [OldestEnvelope]
FROM         dbo.VehicleReg_Documents_QueueTypes AS [qt]
             LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.VehicleReg_Documents_Queue AS [dq] ON dq.QueueID = qt.QueueTypeID
WHERE        dq.IsProcessed = 0
             AND dq.PageNumber = 1
GROUP BY ALL qt.QueueName
ORDER BY     qt.QueueName ASC;
```

And the resulting data set:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><td>Queue</td><td>#ofUnprocessedEnvelopes</td><td>#ofUnassignedEnvelopes</td><td>OldestEnvelope</td></tr><tr><td>Cancellations</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>NULL</td></tr><tr><td>Dealer</td><td>26</td><td>17</td><td>2018-04-06</td></tr><tr><td>Matched to Registration</td><td>93</td><td>82</td><td>2018-04-04</td></tr><tr><td>New Registration</td><td>166</td><td>140</td><td>2018-03-21</td></tr><tr><td>Remaining Documents</td><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2018-04-04</td></tr><tr><td>Renewals</td><td>217</td><td>0</td><td>2018-04-03</td></tr><tr><td>Transfers</td><td>296</td><td>245</td><td>2018-03-30</td></tr><tr><td>Writebacks</td><td>53</td><td>46</td><td>2018-04-09</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I've tried various versions using CTE's and UNION's but I cannot get result set to generate correctly - the records that have no counts will not display or I will have duplicate records displayed.

Any suggestions on how to make this work without the GROUP BY ALL?

Below is one attempt where I tried a CTE with a UNION:

```
;WITH QueueTypes ( QueueTypeID, QueueName )
AS ( SELECT QueueTypeID ,
            QueueName
     FROM   dbo.VehicleReg_Documents_QueueTypes )
SELECT   qt.QueueName AS [Queue] ,
         COUNT ( qt.QueueName ) AS [#ofUnprocessedEnvelopes] ,
         COUNT (   CASE WHEN dq.AssignedToUserID = 0 THEN 1
                        ELSE NULL
                   END
               ) AS [#ofUnassignedEnvelopes] ,
         CONVERT ( VARCHAR (8), MIN ( dq.DocumentDate ), 1 ) AS [OldestEnvelope]
FROM     QueueTypes AS qt
         LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.VehicleReg_Documents_Queue AS dq ON dq.QueueID = qt.QueueTypeID
WHERE    dq.IsProcessed = 0
         AND dq.PageNumber = 1
GROUP BY qt.QueueName
UNION ALL
SELECT   qt.QueueName AS [Queue] ,
         COUNT ( qt.QueueName ) AS [#ofUnprocessedEnvelopes] ,
         COUNT (   CASE WHEN dq.AssignedToUserID = 0 THEN 1
                        ELSE NULL
                   END
               ) AS [#ofUnassignedEnvelopes] ,
         CONVERT ( VARCHAR (8), MIN ( dq.DocumentDate ), 1 ) AS [OldestEnvelope]
FROM     QueueTypes AS qt
         LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.VehicleReg_Documents_Queue AS dq ON dq.QueueID = qt.QueueTypeID
GROUP BY qt.QueueName
```

But the results are not close to being correct:

[image: Result Set]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query doesn't work as it seems to work, because while you outer join table `VehicleReg_Documents_Queue` you dismiss all outer joined rows in the `WHERE` clause, so you are where you would have been with a mere inner join. You may want to consider either moving your criteria to the `ON` clause or make this an inner join right away.

It is also weird that you join queue type and queue not on the queue ID *or* the queue type ID, but on `dq.QueueID = qt.QueueTypeID`. That's like joining employees and addresses on employee number matching the house number. At least that's what it looks like.

(Then why does your queue type table have a queue name? Shouldn't the queue table contain the queue name instead? But this is not about your query, but about your data model.)

`GROUP BY ALL` means: "Please give us all QueueNames, even when the `WHERE` clause dismisses them. I see two possibilities for your query:

1. You do want an outer join actually. Then there is no `WHERE` clause and you can simply make this `GROUP BY qt.QueueName`.
2. You don't want an outer join. Then we want a row per QueueName in the table, which we might not get with simply changing `GROUP BY ALL qt.QueueName` to `GROUP BY qt.QueueName`.

In that second case we want all QueueNames first and outer join your query:

```
select 
  qn.QueueName AS [Queue],
  q.[#ofUnassignedEnvelopes],
  q.[OldestEnvelope]
FROM (select distinct QueueName from VehicleReg_Documents_QueueTypes) qn
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT       qt.QueueName,
               COUNT ( qt.QueueName ) AS [#ofUnprocessedEnvelopes] ,
               COUNT (   CASE WHEN dq.AssignedToUserID = 0 THEN 1
                              ELSE NULL
                         END
                     ) AS [#ofUnassignedEnvelopes] ,
               MIN ( dq.DocumentDate ) AS [OldestEnvelope]
  FROM         dbo.VehicleReg_Documents_QueueTypes AS [qt]
  JOIN         dbo.VehicleReg_Documents_Queue AS [dq] ON dq.QueueID = qt.QueueTypeID
  WHERE        dq.IsProcessed = 0
               AND dq.PageNumber = 1
) q ON q.QueueName = qn.QueueName
GROUP BY ALL qn.QueueName
ORDER BY     qn.QueueName ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks Thor - you were right, my existing query did not work if the value was not there.  Your example does work.  And yes, I agree - the column naming is not consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best corollary here for a 'GROUP BY ALL' into something more ANSI compliant would be a CASE statement. Without knowing your data, it's hard to say for sure if this is 1:1, but I'm betting it's in the ballpark.

```
SELECT qt.QueueName AS [Queue]
    ,COUNT(CASE 
            WHEN dq.IsProcessed = 0
                AND dq.PageNumber = 1
                THEN qt.QueueName
            END) AS [#ofUnprocessedEnvelopes]
    ,COUNT(CASE 
            WHEN dq.AssignedToUserID = 0
                AND dq.IsProcessed = 0
                AND dq.PageNumber = 1
                THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS [#ofUnassignedEnvelopes]
    ,MIN(CASE 
            WHEN dq.IsProcessed = 0
                AND dq.PageNumber = 1
                THEN dq.DocumentDate
            END) AS [OldestEnvelope]
FROM dbo.VehicleReg_Documents_QueueTypes AS [qt]
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.VehicleReg_Documents_Queue AS [dq] ON dq.QueueID = qt.QueueTypeID
GROUP BY qt.QueueName
ORDER BY qt.QueueName ASC;
```

That's a bit uglier because every aggregate has to have the WHERE conditions inside a case statement, but at least you are future proof.

Comment: Thanks - will check this out.